# Upper bound of $m$ such that a convex polygon has exactly $m$ acute inner angles

Tags: geometry

I'm currently practicing some math tasks.
[Here](http://www.olympiade-mathematik.de/pdf/block_a/12104_a.pdf) I found an task (121041) from the 
4th round of the 12th Mathematics Olympics (years ago). The task is:

Show that there is a greatest number $m$ for which the following statement is true!
There is a convex polygon, under whose inner angles exactly $m$ are acute(or sharp?, idk. lets say smaller then 90° :D).

How would you proof this?

Comment: Hint: rephrase in terms of exterior angles.

Comment: You mean There is a convex polygon, under whose exterior angles exactly $m$ are unsharp(?) ? (I think, that the count of sharp inner angles and unsharp exterior angles has to be the same..)

Comment: Exactly. And what do you know about the sum of exterior angles in a (convex) polygon?

Comment: It has to be 360°?

Comment: And is there then a limit to how many external angles can be obtuse (unsharp)?

Comment: I would say the limit is 3? :D

Comment: It's $4$ if you count $90^\circ$ and make a rectangle, but otherwise, that's it. At any rate, it's conclusive proof that there _exists_ a largest $m$, no matter what exactly that largest $m$ _is_. Note that we're specifically asking about convex polygons because otherwise you could make the external angles negative (which corresponds to internal angles of more than $180^\circ$), thus counteracting all the large external angles.

Comment: and how would it be without an convex polygon (without overlaps)?

Comment: Then there is no maximal $m$. Think about a saw (or a star-shape, or anything spiky, really): the outline is a non-convex polygon, and can have as many sharp angles as you want.

Comment: But that is'nt true I think. Think about a octagon. How would u make 8 sharp angles there? I think, that there's also a rule..

Comment: Note that you can't make all angles of an $n$-gon acute if $n$ is large enough. Asking "how many angles of an $n$-gon for a given $n$ can we make acute?" is a different question from the one you have. From looking at the saw shape, the answer is at least $\frac{n+3}2$ for odd $n$, and $\frac{n+2}2$ for $n$ even, but whether that's actually the best you can do, I don't know.