# How many acute interior angles can a polygon have if it is not convex and overlap-free?

Tags: geometry, polygons

Yesterday I posted [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2083942/proof-for-a-task-of-an-earlier-olympics-round?noredirect=1#comment4283421_2083942) question. The Task was:

Show that there is a greatest number $m$ for which the following statement is true!
There is a convex polygon, under whose inner angles exactly $m$ are acute

The solution was, that there is a maximum of $3$.

Now I have asked myself how many acute angles ($m < 90°$) can have a polygon if it is not convex and overlap-free.

Note:
look [here](http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/thumbnail/unbenannttkdecbl3hj_thumb.jpg), there can be more then $\frac {n}{2}$ such angles, but I don't see an reason why there's a maximum amount of acute interior angles (and there is one)!
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What is a "tip" angle? Does it mean an angle less than a right angle, like the $m$ angles in the earlier question?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it. I mean less then 90°

Comment: "acute angles (m>90°) ": That is the definition of an obtuse angle, not an acute angle. Could you clarify?

Comment: ahhhh, I've mistyped. Now!

Comment: Has noone a idea? :/